# How to filter out integers in a group of strings in vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have

```
std::vector<string> x;
std::cout << "Please enter in values ";
std::getline(std::cin, numbers);
numbers.push_back(x)
```

Let's say the user inputted
    3.9823 m/s 34.0 km/s 222 m/s

I was wondering how I'm able to only grab only the numbers in the string and disregard the units? 
I want the values 3.9823, 34.0, and 222

Comment: I think you should use struct{ float number; UNIT unit; }; enum UNIT{ m=0, km, }. And create the vector of struct.

Comment: @Kara You should put a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround

```
std::vector<string> x {"3.9823 m/s", "34.0 km/s", "222 m/s"};

for (int i=0; i<x.size(); i++)
{
    stringstream ss(x[i]);

    float t;
    ss >> t;

    cout << static_cast<int>(t) << endl;
}
```

Output

```
3
34
222
```

Comment: What is auto? I am new to C++ programming

Comment: `auto` is a new keyword in C++11 to support ranged base loop. Anyway, I rewrite the code by index base loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no comment on the robustness of handling input this way, and your question's too self-inconsistent to answer exactly, but to give you an idea:

```
std::vector<double> results;
double n;
for (int i = 0; i < 3 && std::cin >> n; ++i)
{
    results.push_back(n);
    std::string units;
    std::cin >> units;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way; (using [strtof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/) or [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) if you literally wanted only the *integers*.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib> // strtof()

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> x;
    x.push_back("3.9823 m/s");
    x.push_back("34.0 km/s");
    x.push_back("222 m/s");
    char *pEnd;

    float numbers[x.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i<x.size(); ++i){
        numbers[i] = strtof(x[i].c_str(), &pEnd);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<x.size(); ++i){
        std::cout<< numbers[i] << '\n';
    }

}
```

Output;

```
3.9823
34
222
```

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you can use `std::stringstream` with error checking:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::cout << "Please enter in values ";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    std::stringstream is( line );
    std::vector< double > x;
    double temp;

    while (1) {
        is >> temp;
        while ( !is.eof() && (is.bad() || is.fail()) ) {
            is.clear();          // clear the error flag.
            is.ignore(256, ' '); // ignore upto space.
            is >> temp;          // try to read again.
        }
        if (is.eof()) {
            break;
        }
        x.push_back( temp );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++ )
        std::cout << x[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost there, but this wouldn't handle the units in between, no?

Comment: @legends2k Note sure, will check.

Comment: @legends2k Yes you are right, extraction error checking shall have to done. Updated the code.